# Rendering order in JUNG graph visualisation

Tags: graphics, graph, label, jung

I'm using JUNG2 to draw some graphs.

This is the image I get:
http://img841.imageshack.us/img841/205/graphvizkk3312164f020b4.png

I'd like to:

1) change the rendering order (labels should be the last objects to be drawn);

2) add a semi-transparent background to the labels.

3) change background color of the whole image.

Any idea on how to do this?
The JUNG2 documentation is not very extensive on these issues.

Mulone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(1) To do this you'd have to hack the rendering code; I don't believe that we support this at the moment.

UPDATE: I took a closer look.  Actually JUNG does support this without hacking the existing libraries; the easiest way is perhaps to subclass `BasicRenderer` and then override the `render()` method so that things happen in the order that you want.  (I recommend that you render vertices after edges.)  Once you do that, you create an instance of your custom `Renderer`, and call `VisualizationViewer.setRenderer(customRenderer)`.

(2) The labels respect HTML code (i.e., surround your label with `<html></html>` and then put whatever tags you like in it).

(3) `BasicVisualizationServer` (and its subclasses, e.g. `VisualizationViewer`) inherit from `JComponent`, which defines `setBackground(Color)`.

Comment: Thanks! I think it would be beneficial to set the rendering order of labels as the highest.

Comment: You can do this yourself if you like; see the revised response above.